# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning even though using .catch() (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm using Node.js and Express to build a REST api. The database operations are in a separate file called "db.js". Here's the gist of the code:

```
...

const db = require('./db');

app.get('/b50api/workitems/me/:pernr', function (req, rs) {
  db.getWorkItems("200805").then((items, output)=>{
    console.log("ITEMS:", items);
    console.log("OUTPUT:", output);
  }).catch(err => { 
      console.log("ERROR:", err);
  })
})
...
```

When I hit this endpoint the program fails with the error below.

I created a test .js file (below) and this runs just fine:

```
const db = require('./db');
function test() {
    db.getWorkItems("200805").then((items, output)=>{
        console.log("ITEMS:", items);
        console.log("OUTPUT:", output);
    }).catch(err => { 
        console.log("ERROR:", err);
    })
}

test();
```

What am I missing??

Here's the error information when running in my REST api:

```
(node:14612) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
(node:14612) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: p.callNotify is not a function
    at C:\inetpub\wwwroot\PersonnelApps\b50api\node_modules\msnodesqlv8\lib\procedure.js:332:11
    at C:\inetpub\wwwroot\PersonnelApps\b50api\node_modules\msnodesqlv8\lib\procedure.js:305:13
    at C:\inetpub\wwwroot\PersonnelApps\b50api\node_modules\msnodesqlv8\lib\procedure.js:194:9
    at runNextTicks (internal/process/task_queues.js:62:5)
    at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:429:9)
(node:14612) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:14612) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: The error appears to be within the `msnodesqlv8` module, so I'd file a bug report with them. A reproducible case would help though.

Comment: Probably not part of the problem but 
`.then((items, output) => { ... });`
doesn't look right. A promise can deliver only one value.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was it was attempting to connect to the database as some built-in account. I need to change the site to an application and change the account it's running under to the one that needs to authenticate to the SQL Server (along with making that same account one that can log on as a service).